# How do I make CMake re-run a add_custom_command when a dependent file gets modified?

Tags: cmake

I want to have my custom commands rerun every time a file from a list I supply gets modified.

My example: my project has the following files:

- main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
- dep1.txt
- dep2.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(dummy)
set(DummyFiles dep1.txt, dep2.txt)

add_executable(test_dummy main.cpp)

add_custom_command(TARGET test_dummy
COMMENT "ran custom command on file change"
DEPENDS ${DummyFiles}
)
```

My expectation is that **after** I have already configured that project, every time I modify dep1.txt or dep2.txt and reconfigure, CMake will print out the `COMMENT` section above. It however doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **two flows** of command [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/add_custom_command.html): "Generating Files" and "Build Events".

The option `DEPENDS` is available only for the first flow - "Generating Files", which requires `OUTPUT` as the first option.

You use `TARGET` as the first option to the command, which denotes "Build Events" command flow. This command flow doesn't support `DEPENDS` option (there is no such option in the synopsis for this command flow).

> I want to have my custom commands rerun every time a file from a list I supply gets modified.

For that you need to use the **first flow** of the `add_custom_command` with `OUTPUT` option.

You may use dummy file as OUTPUT, so build system could be able to compare the timestamp of this file with the timestamps of the files from `DEPENDS` section. Whenever the timestamp of `OUTPUT` would be found older than the timestamp of one of `DEPENDS`, the command will be re-run.

```
set(DummyFiles dep1.txt dep2.txt)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT dummy.txt
  COMMENT "ran custom command on file change"
  DEPENDS ${DummyFiles}
)

# Need to create a custom target for custom command to work
add_custom_target(my_target ALL
  # Use absolute path for the DEPENDS file.
  # Relative paths are interpreted relative to the source directory.
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dummy.txt
)
```